# How to manipulate items in C#

Tags: xaml, listview, gridview, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I'm making a **Windows Store App** using `C#` and `XAML`. How can I manipulate one single item in a `GridView` or a `ListView`?

According to certain logical conditions, I need to load or not the item in these containers. I have already tried using the property `Visibility.Collapsed` and `Visibility.Visible` of the item, but this just hides or shows the item and it is still loaded in the `GridView`/`ListView`, and is selectable.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have any sample code of what you've tried already? Remember that you should bind the `ListView`'s ItemsSource to a collection and edit the underlying objects, rather than the `ListViewItem`s themselves.

Comment: What you are saying / trying to explain would truly work better if you were to put some of the code here that you are trying or have tried..

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you meant to hide your `GridViewItem` without keeping space in view.
You just need to replace `GridView`'s `ItemsPanel` with `StackPanel` or `VirtualizingStackPanel`.

```
<GridView>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```